# Keras/TensorFlow Running Out of GPU Space

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a model with the keras_segmentation library.  Specifically, the fcn_8_resnet_50 model.  But I am running into an error message where is mentions a bunch of time that I am running out of space and then it crashes.  The error message looks something like this:

```
 Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.08GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

It prints out multiple error messages with information like this, though slightly different sizes.  Then crashes.

When I tried to save the model right after compiling it, before training, the size of the weights seemed to be about 2GiB, so the error message seems accurate.  But the GPU I have says that it has 8 Gb of dedicated memory and 8 Gb of shared memory.  So I'm not sure why 2 Gb would be filling it up.  Does this mean that there are some other processes running on my GPU?

There are two GPUs in the system (an Intel and an NVIDIA), and I thought that normal processes would be running on the Intel, so that the code (with CUDA support) could run alone on the NVIDIA.

Or is there something I am misunderstanding about the space usage of keras model training?

Comment: Yes you are misunderstanding what RAM is used for, it is not only used to store the weights, but also for forward passes, seems you simply do not have enough GPU RAM for this model configuration, did you reduce the batch size to the minimum?

Comment: Unfortunate, I did lower everything to the min for the given model.  I guess I should start looking into a cloud based approach.

Comment: Or just use a smaller model, or a smaller input image size.

Comment: You can try to limit the gpu memory growth, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth